# Why is .data executable?

Tags: linux, executable, elf

According to `readelf`:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  [Nr] Name              Type             Address           Offset
       Size              EntSize          Flags  Link  Info  Align
  [24] .data             PROGBITS         0000000000601040  00001040
       0000000000000051  0000000000000000  WA       0     0     32
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Section to Segment mapping:
Segment Sections... 
00
01
02  
03     .init_array .fini_array .jcr .dynamic .got .got.plt .data .bss
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Program Headers:
  Type           Offset             VirtAddr           PhysAddr
                 FileSiz            MemSiz              Flags  Align
  PHDR           
  INTERP       
  LOAD
  LOAD           0x0000000000000e10 0x0000000000600e10 0x0000000000600e10
                 0x0000000000000281 0x0000000000000288  RW     200000
```

As you can see above .data segment has `W` (Write) and `A` (Alloc) permissions and `.data` is loaded in a `LOAD` section with `R` (Read) `W` (Write).

However, the shellcode in the `.data` section is executable, according to GDB:

```
   0x601060 <bytecode>:     xor    rax,rax
=> 0x601063 <bytecode+3>:   xor    rdi,rdi
```

And I don't know why.  Is this correct?  What am I missing?

Comment: Maybe my interpretation of the output of readelf is wrong ?

Comment: Perhaps users of `readelf` generally just understand this output, but it might be good for you to provide some additional context; what *specifically* stands out to you as strange, what would you have expected to see instead, etc.  Since you don't say what your interpretation is, it's hard for someone to confirm it.

Comment: In fact, as we can see above : (1) .data segment has "W(Write) A(Alloc)" permissions (2) .data is loaded in a LOAD section with "R(Read)W(Write)". BUT : I don't know why, .data will become executable !

Comment: What is it about the GDB output that makes you think the section is executable?

Comment: Note you can edit your post and add additional information inline, rather than post them in comments where it's easy to miss.  I added what you said to the question, but to me it still seems like you haven't provided enough information for someone to be able to help you.

Comment: Could you review/post the output of GDB's `maint info sections`? Also, how have you verified `bytecode` is placed in `.data`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However, the shellcode in the .data section is executable, according to GDB:

The GDB output does *not* tell you that the `.data` section is executable. GDB will happily disassemble any memory you ask it to disassemble.

Try this:

```
(gdb) set $p = (void (*)(void))&bytecode
(gdb) call $p()
```

This should result in a `SIGSEGV` on the first instruction of `bytecode`, because it in fact is *not* executable.